# A strange string initialiaztion

Tags: c++, string

I do really wonder why this program compiles and run correctly:

```
int main(){

    std::string(foo)("strange" " string " "declaration");
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

It will print:

```
strange string declaration
```

Comment: What's so strange about it?

Comment: @axiac, Let's be real here. Neither of these is too common in C++ code, so unfamiliarity is pretty expected. I'm not sure if that's what you were getting at, or just trying to get the question to be more specific, which I can get behind. @OP, focusing on the extra parentheses, one way to make sense of it is that C's declaration syntax models use: `(foo)` is of type `string`.

Comment: Since you did not tell use what exactly you find strange, I picked the "strangest" thing in the post. If that was not what you consider strange, please clarify your question.

Comment: Adjacent string literals (separated by whitespace only) are implicitly concatenated by the preprocessor. More information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal

Comment: @Baum There are at least two issues here - your dupe only addresses one.

Comment: **String literals placed side-by-side are concatenated at translation phase 6 (after the preprocessor). That is, "Hello,"  " world!" yields the (single) string "Hello, world!"** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @NeilButterworth Lacking a clear question in the OP, I had to guess what exactly was considered strange here. Most people probably don't consider that string concatenation strange, but we can add a dupe for that, too if you want.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39327148/3002139 Was that really worth reopening for that? :/

Comment: @Baum It was worth re-opening because the reason for closing it was obviously not the thrust of the OP's question. I have no problem with it being closed now that you have identified a question that addresses the OPs problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I can't close it anymore because I already did once, but go right ahead please.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - You really think the string concatenation was the surprising part?  I am amazed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the strings are being processed by the C preprocessor. When you have strings like this:

```
"foo" "bar"
```

the preprocessor turns them into

```
"foobar"
```

which is then passed on to the C or C++ compiler. This is handy if you want to have long string literals, and still keep them readable:

```
"this is a very long string literal that goes on and on and on and on"
" and then stops"
```

Comment: So no `\\` needed between lines?

Comment: @Won No - the preprocessor ignores any whitespace (including newlines) between string literals.

Comment: I meant this way I don't need to add \ to tell the pre-processor that the remaining text is on the next line.

Comment: @WonFeiHong, Line continuations (`\\` followed by a newline) are used for splitting one token into multiple lines or continuing a piece of code that must remain on a single line (like a macro definition). This literal concatenation technique breaks the literal into two tokens, so there's no need for a continuation.

Comment: Yes that is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because declarations and definitions can have extraneous parenthesis. In this case the parens around foo don't do anything.